# RewriteRule for Javascript/css versioning

Tags: mod-rewrite, versioning

I wrote a utility to handle the versioning of my CSS and JS files for caching purposes, however, I'm struggling to get the RewriteRule setup correctly to load the original file.

The way the versioning utility writes the new URL is as below:

**Local**

```
<script src="20110125/contact.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Global**

```
<script src="../Scripts/js/20110125/core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My RewriteRules strip out the timestamp and load just the path and filename. They are as follows:

```
#rewrite core js
RewriteRule ^(\/Scripts\/[a-z]*\/)[0-9]*\/(.*)  $1$2 [NC]

#rewrite directory level js
RewriteRule .+\/(.+\.js)    $1 [NC]
```

However, when I make a page request I get a 404 on the pages. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a rather bizarre path to your JS files; I'd recommend just using `/js` or `/javascript`, and don't use capital letters in file or path names in a URL. What are you trying to do with your second RewriteRule?

```
#           /js/123456/jquery.js to /js/jquery.js
RewriteRule ^/js/[0-9]+/(.+).js$ /js/$1.js [L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I inherited the directory structure, which made this task for me all that harder as I'm not as well versed in regex. The second rewriterule was to handle directory level js files. The structure has a core file as well as local directory level js files for directory need javascript functionality.